# Javascript function return typeof number. But when typeof is omitted returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have a function that when the return statement is prefaced with **typeof** it says it's a number. But when I remove it it outputs **NaN**.

I don't understand why.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/X3S56/

Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript has `isNaN` function for testing for `NaN`, but be aware that it first tries to coerce its argument to a number, so some values  you may not expect will be considered to be a number, like: `" "`, `true`, `null`, `"0x123"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying `alert(typeof NaN)` might be illuminating.

Although `NaN` *literally* means "not a number", it actually is a kind of `number`. Its meaning is "not a *valid* number" (in the sense of mathematical numbers), but it is still a `number` value (in the sense of Javascript types).

Answer (score 3):

I modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3S56/16/)

You were using  `bookPrice` instead of `this.price`

Comment: Thanks. That actually solved the problem I was trying to get to. But I will choose another answer as the answer to the question posted as not to create confusion. Very much appreciated that however.